# Does "go at each other" "have a go at each other" mean the same thing?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I thought "go at each other" meant fight each other, but I am not sure, and I have been wondering if it's synonymous to "have a go at each other". I haven't been able to find anything on thefreedictionary.

Comment: For all practical purposes, those two phrases mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/have-a-go-at-someone
>
> https://www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/go-at-someone
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/have-a-go-at-someone
>
> https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/go-at-someone-something

Yes, although it's notable that "have a go at" can be specifically words. I've definitely seen the two used as synonymous, though.

Also, this is really minute, but your title should say "**Do** 'X' **and** 'Y' mean the same thing", not "Do**es** 'X' 'Y' mean the same thing". You also have a run-on sentence. Say instead:

> I thought "go at each other" meant fight each other,  but I am not sure **and have** been wondering if it's synonymous to "have a go at each other".

Other than those nitpicks, you're fine on grammar etc. and usage of the two phrases.